# Which technology should I use for on demand background service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Recently I built MEF WCF service, hosted on IIS 8, which receives the command, performs long  background process with SAP ECC and Local DB, then returns the status. So user interface input and output is only the string.

In Internet there are many blog post about WCF Dead and that it's better to use WEB API, and in the future ASP.NET Core, which is even better...

My question is, is there the sense to update the project to ASP.Net Web Api or wait to ASP.Net Core, or it's better to use another technics for this type of work?

Answer (score 0):

Having more people talking about a technology does not means another similar one is completely dead; as an example look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf) to find about incoming WCF implementation for .Net Core.

Of course, this is a subset, as for Web API, MVC or Entity Framework are not uspporting today all features that their Full 4.x versions do.

**Short answer**: you can keep you WCF implmentation and come back later.

**Longuest answer**: look at what features WCF for .NET Core contains (especially for bindings) to see if porting would be easy, or if you need alreday to tihnk about moving to something else.